# How to extract Stored Procedure body in Teradata

Tags: procedure, ddl, teradata, system-tables

I'm trying to extract Stored procedure DDL by querying system tables.
If I run the following query

**select * from dbc.tvm where TableKind = 'P'**

both fields **RequestText** and **CreateText** contain NULL.
Is there any way to query Stored Procedure body apart from using SHOW PROCEDURE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DDL (SPL) for the Stored Procedures is not stored in the data dictionary tables. If you do not retain your DDL in a repository for version control you will need to script the SHOW PROCEDURE commands in a BTEQ script and export them to flat files. This BTEQ script can be generated dynamically if you are creative with your queries against the data dictionary.

Comment: Rob, thank you very much for your answer. Now the situation with Procedures is clear. It looks like Triggers are organized a bit differently as CreateText column of DBC.triggersTbl system table contains DDL.

Comment: @Rob but where is the definition saved actually?

Comment: It is stored in a special row of the "SP" table. Try performing an EXPLAIN on a SHOW PROCEDURE command.